# Angular - How to refresh a JWT token using an Authentication Interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http

When a user logs in they get  token_a. To make any API requests in the application they need  token_b. token_b is generated using token_a.

I have built an authentication interceptor which appends token_b to the header of all subsequent api calls after a user logs in. However, token_b has a short expiry time on it and therefore token_b must be regenerated if it is expired.

**auth.interceptor.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpResponse, HttpClient, HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import { AuthService } from './../services/auth/auth.service';
import { JwtService } from './../services/jwt/jwt.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private httpClient: HttpClient;

    constructor(private auth: AuthService, private jwt: JwtService, private http: HttpBackend) {
        this.httpClient = new HttpClient(http);
    }

    setHeader(req) {

        const authToken = this.auth.getProfileToken();

        const authReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken)
        });

        return authReq;
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

        const InterceptorSkipHeader = 'X-Skip-Interceptor';

        if (req.headers.has(InterceptorSkipHeader)) {
            const headers = req.headers.delete(InterceptorSkipHeader);
            return next.handle(req.clone({ headers }));
        }

        if (this.auth.hasProfileToken() && this.auth.isProfileTokenExpired()) {

            const result = this.refreshToken();
            const ar = this.setHeader(req);
            return next.handle(ar);
        }

        const authReq = this.setHeader(req);
        return next.handle(authReq);

    }


    async refreshToken() {

        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

        return await this.httpClient.post('//api/v1/users/login', { 'token': token })
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
                localStorage.setItem('profile_token', res.token);
                return res;
            });

    }

}
```

In the interceptor function i check to see if the profileToken (token_b) exists and if its expired. if it is i attempt to call refreshToken which sets the new token.

However im finding the refreshToken is not finishing before the interceptor passes on the request.

Answer (score 0):

Since `refreshToken()` is an async function, you need to wait for it to finish before passing on the request. One way is to chain/pipe the `refreshToken()` to `next.handle(ar)`:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

    const InterceptorSkipHeader = 'X-Skip-Interceptor';

    if (req.headers.has(InterceptorSkipHeader)) {
        const headers = req.headers.delete(InterceptorSkipHeader);
        return next.handle(req.clone({ headers }));
    }

    if (this.auth.hasProfileToken() && this.auth.isProfileTokenExpired()) {

        return this.refreshToken().switchMap(() => {
            const ar = this.setHeader(req);
            return next.handle(ar);
        });
    }

    const authReq = this.setHeader(req);
    return next.handle(authReq);

}


refreshToken() {

    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    return this.httpClient.post('//api/v1/users/login', { 'token': token })
        .map((res: any) => {
            localStorage.setItem('profile_token', res.token);
            return res;
        });

}
```

Comment: When using switchmap like your example i get "SwitchMap does not exist on type Promise<Subscription>"

Comment: but what if i dont want to store the refresh token in local storage?